# Python - can't get False variable to turn True

Tags: python, function, variables

```
def firstaction():
    firstact = raw_input(prompt) 
    print distracted_gaze        

    if firstact == "throw rock" and not distracted_gaze:
        distracted_gaze = True 
        print distracted_gaze 
        firstaction()

    elif firstact == "throw spear" and distracted_gaze:
        secondaction()



distracted_gaze = False 
firstaction()
```

I can't get the if statement to return:

```
distracted_glaze = True.
```

Would appreciate help. Thanks

....

Ok, so now I seem to have fixed this error. Here is my new code:

```
    def firstaction():
    firstact = raw_input(prompt) 
    global distracted_gaze
    print distracted_gaze  

    elif firstact == "throw rock" and not distracted_gaze:
        print "Now he is distracted. He won't hear anything you throw at him!"
        distracted_gaze = True 
        print distracted_gaze 
        firstaction()

    elif firstact == "throw spear" and distracted_gaze:
        print "He's dead! A door appears behind him..."
        secondaction()

global distracted_gaze
distracted_gaze = False 
firstaction()
```

What is confusing me now is: why did I have to define the variable as 'global' outside the function and then use then type 'global distracted_gaze' in the function too? (I tried running the script 2 times after both defining the variable as global outside the function and then using it inside the function without typing 'global' in front of it, and also by typing 'global' inside the function in front of the variable and defining the variable without using 'global' outside the function. Both times Powershell outputted errors).

Is that standard? Because this tutorial (http://www.python-course.eu/global_vs_local_variables.php) doesn't say that you have to do that - in fact quite the opposite. If you define a variable as 'global' the first time then whenever you use the variable it will be 'global' by default unless redefined locally within a function.

Comment: You cannot start an `elif` statement without preceding it with an `if` statement

Comment: There is an if-statement before but I've taken it out to make the code shorter and more presentable

Comment: Trying to condense your code for a SO question is a good thing, but you've accidentally removed too much. We can't debug an `elif` statement without the leading `if`. It's the same as if you asked us to debug a variable's value, but left out the assignment to the variable. Please add it back in. Whenever possible, try to include an example that is complete enough for SO users to copy the code into a file and run it so they can observe the questionable behavior themselves.

Comment: I have done so - however the editor wouldn't let me enter the 'else' statement because it was 'too much code.'

Answer (score 1):

There are bunch of problems with the code:

1. Replace  `elif firstact...` with `if firstact...`
2. You accessing `distracted_gaze` which is not in localscope
3. The `prompt` is not defined. Replace it with something like `"Enter here "`

Comment: There is an if-statement before but I've taken it out to make the code shorter and more presentable.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `global distracted_gaze` in your `firstaction` function (in addition to fixing its broken Python code, as others have observed:-).  The code you're showing is clearly not the one you're running, or else you'd get a syntax error.  But that's not the core of your problem.

Rather, the issue is: Python considers every barename that's bound in a function to be **local** to that function -- unless you specifically tell it otherwise with a `global` statement (or in recent Python 3 releases a `nonlocal` one, but, let's not get into that:-).

This discourages you from using global variables, which is a good thing since it's a terrible programming practice.  At least, it forces you to be very explicit about the fact you **are** using said terrible programming practice -- better than nothing:-).

Other issues unrelated to the question you ask, but very related to your weird choice about which code to show, `first_action` is an infinite recursion the way you presented it (I guess the `if` you're peculiarly decided to hide is what terminates the recursion? hard to guess...).